# Can you use Rust to write Firefox add-ons/extensions?

Tags: firefox, rust, browser-addons

Mozilla has the [Oxidation project](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Oxidation):

> The goal of Oxidation is to make it easier and more pleasant to use Rust in Firefox, and correspondingly to increase the amount of Rust code in Firefox.

But it does not mention anything about whether Rust is supported for add-ons or not.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851109/what-programming-language-required-to-created-a-firefox-plugin

Comment: Hum, I doubt that Rust would be an user-friendly way to write add-ons. There is no Rust ABI, so you have to use the C ABI with FFI. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708483/idiomatic-rust-plugin-system/44715785

Comment: Maybe you can write them in rust and compile them to WebAsm. But i dont know if WebExtensions support WebAsm.

Comment: @Boiethios There is no C ABI, it's the Operating system ABI if you want but C same as Rust don't define their ABI in their specification.

Comment: @gotocoffee If it does not, you should bring up the idea because it is a nice one!

Answer (score 16):

Nowadays, you can do with WebExtensions and [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) ([guide how to compile here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/WebAssembly/Rust_to_wasm)). You then just embed it as `wasm` code in your add-on like in any website.

This [add-on e.g. did so](https://github.com/lukaslueg/macro_railroad_ext). ([found on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/a40yfr/can_i_write_a_firefox_webextension_in_rust/))

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to write a complete add-on in Rust. Although you could use Native Messaging to communicate from the add-on to a binary built with Rust. When an add-on uses native messaging the browser starts a native binary on the system and exchanges messages encoded in JSON over stdio.

Mozilla has [detailed information about native messaging on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging).